# Angular Material - How to position text next to image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

i'm tryning to make text next image but it's offset 
any idea please?

**DEMO**

http://jsbin.com/dugokozame/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

Change the position of image div and also added float to the css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="sandbox">
    <md-content layout="column"  flex layout-padding layout-align="center center">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">   
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center start">
                <div layout="column" flex="80">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div layout="row" layout-align="center start">
                <div layout="column" flex="80">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
                <div layout="column" flex="80">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </md-content>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
img
 {
        width: 350px;
        height: 350px;
        background-size: cover;
        border-radius: 100px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 170px;
        float: left;
 }
```

Comment: @Damiano I am sorry i didnt mean to but that what i also thought off! Do you want me to delete it?

Comment: @Damiano I have edited my code to be something out of the box and bit different then yours! :)

Comment: No problem, sorry for that, not harmed.

Answer (score 0):

To align the bottom lorem ipsum to the right side of image use:

```
.image-circle {
    ...
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Someone else suggested to remove `background-size: cover;` which will result aligning the circle's inner text center. So it depends what you want to achieve. Could you please explain it better?

Answer (score 0):

In the below example multiple rows of text is placed beside image with help of table.
here a row  is devided into two coloumns.First coloumn contains image and the second coloumn contains multiple text placed inside  for creating seperate rows within this coloumn

```
<table class="table table">

  <!-- On cells (`td` or `th`) -->
  <tr *ngFor="let img of search_cat" style="border-bottom: 1px; border-color: greenyellow">
<td class="active" style="width: 50%"> <a href="#" [routerLink]="['/details']" [queryParams]="img" routerLinkActive="active">
 <img style="width: 100%;" src="{{img.offer_banner}}"></a>
</td>
<td class="active">
  <tr>
    <p style="color: deepskyblue">{{img.product_name}}</p>
</tr>
<tr style="width:25%">
<td>
  <s style="width:50%; color: crimson">₹{{img.actual_price}}</s>
</td>
<td>
  <p style="color:  goldenrod;width:50%;"> ₹{{img.selling_price}}</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>{{img.discount}}</tr>
<tr>{{img.offer_details}} </tr>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```